# Obtain a Wordpress Website with a Proxmox container available from outside with https (ssl encryption)

Tags: ssl, container, lxc, proxmox, letsencrypt

My prelimanary actions:

- setting up a ddns hostname with noip service (ok)
- configured to automatically keep alive the association on my home router(ok)
- installed a proxmox server v8 (ok)
- create a lxc container with model "debian11-turnkey-wordpress" with a static IP (ok)
- configured port forwarding 80,443 on router to point the lxc wordpress container(ok)

The current situation:

The website in lan is ok
When I try to access from internet with the ddns hostname it works the first time and then goes in ssl cert error both with http/https
When I try to get let's encrypt certificate with the selfconsole panel it fail in fatal error

My questions: How i can implement correctly the ssl certification in the container to use https from internet to lan container inside proxmox with a forwarding from outside to home network lan?

The configuration must be applied only on containers or there is somthing to do in general in the proxmox os, instead, to have all the newest containers ssl encrypted by default?

Comment: Proxmox doesn't care what you do with the container. If you've got a container running a web server then that is where you need to put your certificate. The only exception is when you are proxying on the router rather than port forwarding

Comment: Ok, so what I need to do to have a proxmox debian11-turnkey-wordpress container accesible from internet using the ddns hostname that identify my router that forward 80,443 request to it with a correct ssl encryption?

Comment: Install an SSL certificate into your container's web server

Comment: You should investigate why Lets Encrypt failed in your container - check the logs  if any - did it fail due to dependency errors? Permissions?

Comment: Unless you've set up a redirect from http to https you shouldn't need a certificate to access your website on http (port 80). You can test with that. And then go and get (say) a LetsEncrypt certificate for the https service

Comment: In the selfconsole menu in "Install let's encrypt certificate" It told me something about to check dns entries...I've configured google dns servers and a ping with the ddns hostname reply correctly form container works...maybe the domain name, that let's encrypt config procedure ask to me, is not only the ddns noip hostname (ex. example.ddns.net) but something else? I cant find any log about this, I'm searching... the error is "FATAL: dehydrated exited with a non-zero exit code" and a note to "check the log file" (without even noting where the log file is)

Comment: I know Chris that with port 80 it would work, but it doesn't....So can I directly setup an ssl https but let's encrypt install procedure won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bad configuration of port 443 on the router. Problem solved.